# The sum of the current ages of Ahmad and Henry is $54$.

Tags: word-problem

The sum of the current ages of Ahmad and Henry is $54$. When Ahmad were the same age as Henry's current age, Henry was $18$. What is Ahmad's current age?

Here is what I thought

$A + H = 54$

$A-t = H, H = 18$

$t$ = passed time

I can't think anyhing more. Can I get your thinkings?

Comment: Still thinking on it but no idea about how to write the correct equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A + H = 54$$
$$A-t = H$$
$$H-t=18$$
Three equations, three unknowns.

Comment: Can you explain how you found them?

Comment: Exactly the same as your setup. The variable $t$ is the elapsed time. But $t$ is the same for _both_ Ahmad and Henry.

Comment: You're awesome! Can you give hint how to determine it? because there are three unknowns.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: Solve the third equation for $t$. Substitute the result for $t$ in the second equation. That eliminates $t$. Now you have two equations in two unknowns.

Comment: Okay, I solved it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Ahmad is $A$ years old, Henry is $H$ years old ($A+H=54$).

$H$ years later from now,  Ahmad will be $A+H$ years old, Henry will be $2H$ years old.

$H-A$ years later from now, Ahmad will be $H$ years old, Henry will be $2H-A$ years old. The task indicated that when Ahmad was $H$ years old, Henry was $18$ years old, so:

> $$2H-A=18$$

We have this set of equations:

> ${\begin{cases}A+H=54\\2H-A=18\end{cases}\Rightarrow {\begin{cases}A=30\\H=24\end{cases}}}$

Comment: I didn't get your explanation too much.

Comment: First you consider $H$ years later from now, then you consider $A$ years before that point (which means $H-A$ years from now). Doing so, Ahmad will have the same age as indicated in the task, which means Henry must also have the same age as indicated in the task. Which part do you find difficult to understand?